# Not Loading the XML file

Tags: android, xml, google-maps-android-api-2

Hi dears I am working on google maps V2 but i having this problem in logcat

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mine4.timedistancemeasurement/com.example.mine4.timedistancemeasurement.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
            at com.example.mine4.timedistancemeasurement.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My layout file is this. I am just adding my fragment code here which I think is creating prblem

```html
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_distance_time" />
```

and my permissions are

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.mine4.timedistancemeasurement.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mine4.timedistancemeasurement.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAYH2YM978KgmYYTUcKoTLCnfsFUNCfwps" />
```

and my activity look like this

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap map;
    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
    TextView tvDistanceDuration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

now please tell me the solution

Comment: Add `<meta-data>` under `<application>` tag

Comment: well u are creating fragment activity and see the error so you need to make your class extended with fragment only and initialize your map in oncreate

Comment: map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                          .getMap();

Comment: Whats your minimum SDK version?

Answer (score 0):

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

change to

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

tell me it's work or not